# php delete empty array indexes

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have two+ Arrays which I set in a while loop.

Every array have a dependence to the other array by the index. And every array have duplications on the same index.

What I want to do is, to delete the duplications and after that to delete the empty indexes of each array, so that all arrays have the same positions like before but without duplications.

What I have tried is this:

```
    $array1 = array_unique($array1);    
    $array2 = array_unique($array2); 

    print_r($array1);
    echo "<br>";
    print_r($array2);
    echo "<br>";

    sort($array1);
    sort($array2);  

    print_r($artNrArray);
    echo "<br>";
    print_r($pnameArray);
    echo "<br>";
```

This is the output:

```
Array ( 
      [0] => 0100_64 
      [9] => 1999_13 
      [18] => 5999_12 
      [19] => 0204_22 
      [21] => 0241_75 ) 
Array ( 
      [0] => intKab-4xAWG22-S-oE-oE-K3 
      [9] => Käbel 
      [18] => Kabel_test123 
      [19] => K-A21-V-IBIS-13-3-4-0-0-0m 
      [21] => K-CAN-17-2m )
Array ( 
      [0] => 0100_64 
      [1] => 0204_22 
      [2] => 0241_75 
      [3] => 1999_13 
      [4] => 5999_12 ) 
Array ( 
      [0] => K-A21-V-IBIS-13-3-4-0-0-0m 
      [1] => K-CAN-17-2m 
      [2] => Kabel_test123 
      [3] => Käbel 
      [4] => intKab-4xAWG22-S-oE-oE-K3 )
```

The problem if I sort the arrays is, that the dependence of the array contet is changed. What I want to have is this:

```
Array ( 
      [0] => 0100_64 
      [1] => 1999_13 
      [2] => 5999_12 
      [3] => 0204_22 
      [4] => 0241_75 ) 
Array ( 
      [0] => intKab-4xAWG22-S-oE-oE-K3 
      [1] => Käbel 
      [2] => Kabel_test123 
      [3] => K-A21-V-IBIS-13-3-4-0-0-0m 
      [4] => K-CAN-17-2m )
```

I have to use array_unique() to delete the duplications.

So how can I delete the array indexes with empty value and contraxt the array from 0 - 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the next:

```
$array1 = array_values(array_unique($array1));    
$array2 = array_values(array_unique($array2));
```